# ARRAY NUEVO CON TODOS LOS VALORES ACUMULADOS

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando crear un nuevo array con los valores acumulados, pero no encuentro el metodo, el metodo reduce me devuelve un solo valor con la suma de todos los valores, pero lo que necesito es un nuevo array sumando el acumulado.

Probe con un bucle pero tampoco se por donde seguir..

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let sum = [array[0]];
for (let i = 1; i <array.length; i++) {
  sum += array[i];
}
console.log(sum);
```

si alguien me puede echar una mano.. gracias!

Comment: Cambia el `let sum = [array[0]];` por `let sum = 0;` para que entienda que esa variable es numérica.

Comment: Prueba esto: `let sum = [ array.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + curr, 0) ];`

Comment: el problema es que necesito un nuevo array con todos los acumulados, no un acumulado final, necesitaria un array con " [1,3,6,10].. y con reduce solo me duelve el 10 final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día,

Otra opción con `map`

```js
const sumaAcumulada = (sum => value => sum += value)(0);

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].map(sumaAcumulada));
```

`sumaAcumulada` es la función `value => sum += value`, con el valor de `sum` inicializado en cero. Cada vez que la función es invocada, `sum` se actualiza y será igual al valor del resultado previo, es decir, del índice [n-1] cuando se esté evaluando [n].

Comment: Buena respuesta, aunque no la entiendo demasiado.  ¿podrías explicar un poco la línea de **const** para comprenderlo mejor? gracias!

Comment: @masterguru,  he agregado una explicación, digamos que es como una forma de recursion donde el valor de sum[n] es igual a sum[n-1] + valor de la iteración actual.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Mi lio de comprensión era más bien con las funciones flecha, y no comprendía esa sintaxis que habias puesto. Ahora ya creo que sí, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Si necesitas un nuevo array con todos los acumulados prueba esto:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let sum = 0
let array_sum = []
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  sum += array[i];
  array_sum.push(sum)
}
console.log(array_sum);
```

donde, mediante el método [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), vamos agregando las sumas parciales a la variable de array **array_sum**